# Gaussian Mixture Division

Tags: distributions, inference, gaussian-mixture-distribution, graphical-model, data-augmentation

In the study of probabilistic graphical models (PGMs), the loopy belief update propagation (LBUP) message passing algorithm requires the division of unnormalised probability distributions. If the dividend and divisor are both mixtures of Gaussians,
$$ f (\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha_{i} \cdot \mathcal{N} (\mathbf{x} | \boldsymbol{\mu}_{i}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{i} )  $$ and 
$$ g (\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{j=1}^{M} \gamma_{j} \cdot \mathcal{N} (\mathbf{x} | \boldsymbol{\nu}_{j}, \mathbf{S}_{j} )  $$ respectively, is there a principled method of approximating the quotient,
$$ h(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{ g (\mathbf{x}) } \text{?} $$

It was suggested to me that it might be possible to "data augment" the mixture model with allocation variables, placing it in a conjugate exponential family and thus making the division tractable. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about data augmentation; is this a reasonable suggestion? If it is reasonable, how would I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest possible approximation is to use a Gaussian equivalent for the denominator and divide component wise,

\begin{align}
h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \approx \frac{f(x)}{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{v}_{eq}, \mathbf{S}_{eq})}
\end{align}

where $(\mathbf{v}_{eq}, \mathbf{S}_{eq})$ are respectively, the mean and covariance of the Gaussian approximation.

Note that the division of two Gaussian has a closed form solution, which, in this case, results in,

\begin{align}
h(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i .\frac{|\mathbf{S}_{eq} - \mathbf{\Sigma}_i|}{|\mathbf{\Sigma}_i|}.\frac{1}{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}_i|\mathbf{v}_{eq}, \mathbf{S}_{eq} - \mathbf{\Sigma}_i)}.\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{\mu}_{n,i}, \mathbf{\Sigma}_{n,i})
\end{align}

where $(\mathbf{\mu}_{n,i}, \mathbf{\Sigma}_{n,i})$ are,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\Sigma}_{n,i} &= (\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}_{i} - \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}_{eq})^{-1} \\
\mathbf{\mu}_{n,i} &= \mathbf{\Sigma}_{n,i}[\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}_{i}\mathbf{\mu}_{i} - \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}_{n,i}\mathbf{\mu}_{n,i} ]
\end{align}

Note that for proper probability density functions, it is required that $(\mathbf{S}_{eq} - \mathbf{\Sigma}_i)$ is positive definite.

Alternatively you can approximate the individual fraction $\frac{f(x,i)}{g(x)}$ as a Gaussian by computing first and second moments using Monte-Carlo methods.